# Can a javascript class return another class?

Tags: javascript, oop

Is it a bad practice to return a class inside the method of another class?

Example: createBlockClass method

```js
class BlockBuilder {
    constructor (methodForBlock) {
        this.methodForBlock = methodForBlock;
    };

    createBlockClass () {
        const method = this.methodForBlock.bind(this.methodForBlock);
        return class Block {
            constructor(title) {
                this.title = title;
            };
            method = method;
        }
    }
};

const blockBuilder = new BlockBuilder(() => console.log('Hello, world!!!'));
const Block = blockBuilder.createBlockClass();
const block1 = new Block("block one");
const block2 = new Block("block two");
block1.method();
block2.method();
```

I need to receive a method as a parameter and add it to the block class before creating any instance

Comment: You don't need a new definition of the Block class each time you want to assign a method to it.  Instead assign the method to a member of an instance of Block. You need to decide what the type of that method is in advance though. e.g. Consumer, Predicate, Function, Supplier. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class in javascript is a function sprinkled with syntactic sugar.  (reason: in javascript 'prototypal inheritance instead of  the "regular" class-based inheritance as in e.g. python, java).

A function in javascript is a first-class citizen, so a function can be both the input, as well as the output of another function.

This leads to the following deductions/conclusions:

A function can output another function.

A function can output a class.

A class can output another class.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to create a class:

```js
function createBlockClass(methodForBlock) {
  return class Block {
    constructor(title) {
      this.title = title;
    }
    method = methodForBlock;
  }
}

const Block = createBlockClass(() => console.log('Hello, world!!!'));

const block1 = new Block("block one");
const block2 = new Block("block two");

block1.method();
block2.method();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it normal to return a class? or, is it a bad practice?

Comment: Normally I don't see why it would be necessary, but if you want to do it , I'm not stopping you.